# Change route view based on route name

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-router4

At the moment I am displaying google maps in a div, whenever I change route, I want to replace the view with another view. I tried to set it as below, but it doesn't work

```
 .map-col(ref="mapCol" v-if="route.name == 'Adventure'")
 .map-col(v-else)
    router-view
```

```
{
        path: "/adventures/id",
        name: "Adventure",
        component: Adventure,
        children: [
       
          {
            path: "points/id/clues/new",
            name: "NewClue",
            component: NewClue
          }
        ]
      }
```

console.log(route.name) Outputs `Adventure` so it's fine.

Error I am getting
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` and screen page going fully white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`$route`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties) instead of `route` :

```
.map-col(ref="mapCol" v-if="$route.name == 'Adventure'")
```

Comment: Once I change routes, then go back to Adventure route, it doesn't load my map, do you might know why? I am using onMounted to load everything.

Comment: `router-link(:to="{name: 'Adventure'}")` , when I go back to this view it's like mounted not working.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/k01j29Z1 when I go to this view normally it's fine, but when I change the route, and go back to this view from other route the map doesn't load at all.